# Async Job in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to achieve this? I mean, having a job forming part of a pipeline that gets triggered by the execution of it, but that does not affect the result of the entire pipeline?

An example use case would be to generate coverage or vulnerabilities reports on this async job. We probably don't want to stop the entire pipeline while this gets executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Using `needs:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) allows you to implement this. If you don't want the status of that can be handled by `allow_failure:`

One example would be as follows:

```yaml
vuln_scan:
  stage: .post
  script:
    - make scan
  needs: []  # start immediately
  allow_failure: true
```

To break down everything here:

This would create a job `vuln_scan` in the `.post` stage (a special stage that's always last in the pipeline)  Because it's in the `.post` stage, it won't block any other jobs in the pipeline. It also uses `needs: []` which makes the job run immediately, so it doesn't wait for any other jobs. Finally, setting `allow_failure: true` means the outcome of the job will not impact the overall pass/fail outcome of the whole pipeline.

You could also explicitly specify other jobs in `needs:` if, for example, you need artifacts from previous jobs.

```yaml
coverage:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make coverage
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .coverage

upload_coverage:
  stage: .post
  needs: # run as soon as the specified job(s) finish
    - coverage 
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - upload_coverage.sh
```